# HashMap get comes back with null even tho key is in it

Tags: java, enums, hashmap

I'm trying to create a swing chessboard with icons and i have trouble with putting the icons  onto the JButtons using a HashMap.
Here are the classes that i'm working with:

Main Class

```
public class GameGUI  extends JFrame {
    private JButton tiles[][] = new JButton[8][8];
    private HashMap<PieceKey, ImageIcon> icons = new HashMap<>();

    public GameGUI(){
        //swing shenannigans

        initImages();

        Tile[][] fenTiles = game.getFen().getTiles();
        for(int row = 0; row <= 7; row++){
            for(int column = 0; column <= 7; column++){
                Piece piece = fenTiles[row][column].getPiece();
                if(piece != null) {
                    tiles[row][column].setIcon(icons.get(new PieceKey(piece.getType(), piece.getColor())));
                }
            }
        }


    }

    public void initImages(){
        icons.put(new PieceKey(PieceType.pawn, Team.white), new ImageIcon("pieces/wpawn.png"));
        //.....
        }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        GameGUI asd = new GameGUI();
    }
}
```

PieceKey class

```
public class PieceKey {
    PieceType type;  //enum
    Team color;      //enum

    public PieceKey(PieceType type, Team color) {
        this.color = color;
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(this == o)
            return true;
        if(!(o instanceof PieceType))
            return false;
        PieceKey key = (PieceKey) o;
        return this.type == key.type && this.color == key.color;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return type.toString().hashCode() * color.toString().length();
    }
}
```

Team enum

```
public enum Team {
    white, black;
}
```

PieceType enum

```
public enum PieceType {
    pawn, rook, knight, bishop, king, queen;
}
```

My problem is that whenever i call

```
icons.get(new PieceKey(piece.getType(), piece.getColor()));
```

It return null, so i cant put the icons onto the buttons, it works fine if i do it manually so the problem is with the HashMap. I tried to override the equals and the hashcode function in the PieceKey class but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think @jccampenero found the issue. But if you are using a recent version of Java you might want to consider using a `record` for `PieceKey` to avoid these problems.

Comment: That is a very good point @sprinter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be in your `PieceKey` `equals` method. You are using incorrectly `PieceType` while using `instanceof`:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(this == o)
        return true;
    // Please, note this, it will always return false, and the `Map`
    // `equals` method for `get` and `put` will not work
    if(!(o instanceof PieceType))
        return false;
     PieceKey key = (PieceKey) o;
     return this.type == key.type && this.color == key.color;
}
```

If should be:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(this == o)
        return true;
    // Please, note this
    if(!(o instanceof PieceKey))
        return false;
     PieceKey key = (PieceKey) o;
     return this.type == key.type && this.color == key.color;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you i was searching for something like that for 5 hours now, guess i just needed a second pair of eyes to find it! Cheers!

Comment: You are very welcome @SanyiLukácsi. I agree with you, all of us sometimes need a second pair of eyes to find the problem. I am very glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by jccampanero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70088949/642706) seems correct about you having a problem with the implementation details of your override of `Object :: equals`.

## Record

Another solution is to avoid even needing to write your own `equals` and `hashCode`. If your `PieceKey` class is meant primarily to transparently and immutable carry data, define the class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

Your entire class reduces to this simple short line.

```
public record PieceKey ( PieceType type , Team color ) {}
```

As a record, the compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

You make an instance in the same way as with a conventional class.

```
new PieceKey( PieceType.pawn , Team.white )
```

Bonus tip: In Java 16 and later, as part of the work done to create the records feature, we can now declare records, enums, and interfaces locally.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your IDE to generate your hashCode and equals implementation.

The most default implementation you should have should be something like:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return Objects.hash(type, color); // java.util.Objects
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o == this) return true;
  if (!(o instanceof PieceKey) return false;
  PieceKey other = (PieceKey) o;
  return Objects.equals(type, other.type)
      && Objects.equals(color, other.color);
}
```

Note that you don't need this at all with Java 17 records:

```
public record PriceKey(PieceType type, Team color) {}
```

- `hashCode()` and `equals()` are by generated using type/color.
- `type` and `color` are `final` by default.